# How can I make a user control move in runtime In wpf c#

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a user control that I want to move in runtime when I hold and drag it 
In another words I want to make the user control moves like a normal window

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15354/Dragging-Elements-in-a-Canvas

Comment: -1 for a really poor question, and an evident lack of research.

Comment: I don't want it in a canvas ... I want it in a the whole window !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand what you need that will help you

you can easily do it from `Behavior` that you can reach it from `Assets` called `MouseDragElementBehavior`

to use it just drag it and drop it in your user control